# Geometry Problem Concerning Lengths with a Square and Two Right Triangles

Tags: geometry

Square $ABCD$ has side length 13, and points $E$ and $F$ are exterior to the square such that $BE = DF = 5$ and $AE = CF = 12$. Find $EF^2$.

[Click Here for the Attached Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYuX0.png)

Comment: Hint: Try to use analytical geometry.

Comment: What is $F^2$??

Comment: $F^2$ is not referred to in the question. It refers to $EF^2$, which is the square of the length of segment $EF$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
First, by Pythagoras, triangles $ABE$ and $CDF$ are right triangles. We extend lines $\overline{EA}$, $\overline{EB}$, $\overline{FC}$, and $\overline{FD}$ to construct quadrilateral $EGFH$.

[image]

Right triangles $ABE$ and $CDF$ are congruent, so $\angle DCF = \angle EAB$, which means $\angle GDA = \angle EAB$. Also, $AD = AB$, so triangles $EAB$ and $GDA$ are congruent. Hence, $\angle AGD = \angle AEB = 90^\circ$.

Also, $GE = AG + AE = 5 + 12 = 17$, and $GF = DF + DG = 5 + 12 = 17$, so triangle $EGF$ is a right isosceles triangle. Then $EF = GE \sqrt{2} = 17 \sqrt{2}$, so $EF^2 = (17 \sqrt{2})^2 = \boxed{578}$.

Answer (score 3):

[image] 
Join $EF$ and $BD$. Let them interesect at $O$. Triangles $FOD$ and $EOB$ are congruent. So $O$ is the midpoint of $EF$. Also it is the meeting point of the diagonals. Since angles $AEB$ and $AOB$ are right angles, quadrilateral $AOBE$ is cyclic. Now applying [Ptolemy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem) we get, $EF=17\sqrt2$. Therefore $EF^2=578$.